# h264 u(v) decode of frame_num, pic_order_cnt_lsb and slice_group_change_cycle

Tags: avfoundation, h.264, decoding

According to "Slice Header Syntax" (described in ITU-T Rec. h264), `frame_num`, `pic_order_cnt_lsb` and `slice_group_change_cycle` have `u(v)` descriptor, which is the unsigned integer using variable number of bits.

The doc states that

> "the number of bits varies in a manner dependent on the value of other
>   syntax elements."

Do you know how to figure out the number of bits used to store `frame_num`, `pic_order_cnt_lsb` and `slice_group_change_cycle`?

[The cited documentation points to `read_bits(n)` function, unfortunately I cannot figure it out by myself. Can you help?]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other bitstream values define the number of bits to read.

#### `frame_num`

> is used as an identifier for pictures and **shall be represented by log2_max_frame_num_minus4 + 4 bits** in
>   the bitstream.

Here is what FFmpeg does, for example:

```cpp
log2_max_frame_num_minus4 = get_ue_golomb(&h->gb);
// ...
sps->log2_max_frame_num = log2_max_frame_num_minus4 + 4;
// ...
h->frame_num = get_bits(&h->gb, h->sps.log2_max_frame_num);
```

#### `pic_order_cnt_lsb`

> specifies the picture order count modulo MaxPicOrderCntLsb for the top field of a coded frame or for a coded field. **The size of the pic_order_cnt_lsb syntax element is** log2_max_pic_order_cnt_lsb_minus4 + 4 bits.
>
> The value of the pic_order_cnt_lsb shall be in the range of 0 to MaxPicOrderCntLsb – 1, inclusive.

#### `slice_group_change_cycle`

> The value of slice_group_change_cycle is represented in the bitstream by the following number of bits
>   Ceil( Log2( PicSizeInMapUnits ÷ SliceGroupChangeRate + 1 ) )

Example of bit reading: [SliceHeader.cpp, line 170](http://read.pudn.com/downloads152/sourcecode/zip/668121/H264Decoder/SliceHeader.cpp__.htm)

Comment: Roman, great answer. It is exactly what I was looking for. I've also check it in the "H.264/AVC Reference Software Decoder Documentation" available [here](http://iphome.hhi.de/suehring/tml/doc/ldec/html/index.html)</br>